# jRuby threading - am I doing it right?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

Would you mind telling me if I am threading correctly in Ruby?

I have an array `items` that I want to process in 16 threads, wait until all the threads have finished, and then do more work.

Here is my code;

```
    chunks = items.each_slice(items.count / 16).to_a
puts chunks.length

queue = Queue.new
semaphore = Mutex.new
threads = []

puts '[+] Building Queue'
chunks.each do |chunk|
    threads << Thread.new {
        chunk.each do |item|
            array = []
            metadata.each do |m|
                array << m.evaluate(item) rescue ''
            end
semaphore.synchronize {
    queue << array.join(20.chr)
}
        end
    }
end
puts '[+] Running threads'
threads.each{|t|t.join; puts 'Threads done'}

#Do more work here, queue should be fully populated
puts '[+] Writing to file'
File.open('E:/Export.dat', 'wt', encoding: 'UTF-16LE') do |f|
    until queue.empty?
        unit = queue.pop(true) rescue nil
        if unit
            f.puts unit
        end
    end
end
```

The code runs, but doesn't give me the performance I would expect from threading, is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: Is your ruby interpreter allowed to run on multiple threads?

Comment: Yes it is, I was just trying to establish if the logic of my code was sound

Comment: How many CPUs do you have available?

Comment: The logic is Ok. Thats why I am asking the question. Should be faster.

Comment: Where do you use `queue`?

Comment: Updated my original question, however, it is insignificant at this point as the code is taking a long time before even actioning the queue. The box CPU is E5-2630 v2 @ 2.40 GHz (16 cores) and 32 logical processors

Comment: You are syncrhonizing your threads.

Comment: So there is no need for the synchronize? I can just do `queue << array.join(20.chr)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you will see a performance improvement because each thread is blocking to add the result to the queue. The Queue class is thread safe so you don't need a Mutex to guard it.

To make multi-threaded code work better, you want each thread to operate as independently as possible. The below implementation should improve the performance.

```
chunks = items.each_slice(items.count / 16).to_a
puts chunks.length

queue = Queue.new
threads = []

puts '[+] Building Queue'
chunks.each do |chunk|
    threads << Thread.new do
        chunk.each do |item|
            array = []
            metadata.each do |m|
                array << m.evaluate(item) rescue ''
            end
            queue << array.join(20.chr)
        end
    end
end
puts '[+] Running threads'
threads.each{|t|t.join; puts 'Threads done'}

#Do more work here, queue should be fully populated
puts '[+] Writing to file'
File.open('E:/Export.dat', 'wt', encoding: 'UTF-16LE') do |f|
    until queue.empty?
        unit = queue.pop(true) rescue nil
        if unit
            f.puts unit
        end
    end
end
```

You also need to measure where the bottlenecks are in your code.  Simple timers (difference between start and end times) are fine. If the evaluation of metadata takes 10ms with threads and 100ms without, and writing to the file takes 1000ms. Then you aren't going to notice a big difference from multi-threading.